# Show that $|A\cup B|+|A\cap B| =|A|+| B|$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

I want to show that $|A\cup B|+|A\cap B| =|A|+| B|$. I know that $|A\cup B| = A\cup(B-A)$ and that $B-A = B-(A\cap B)$. We also know that $A$ and $B$ and Lebesgue measurable.

Here is my approach:

$$|A\cup B|+|A\cap B| = |A\cup(B-A)|+|B-(A\cap B)|$$
Since $A$ and $(B-A)$ are disjoint sets I can say
$$= |A|+|(B-A)|+|B-(A\cap B)|$$
and since $(A\cap B) \subset B$ I can say
$$= |A|+|(B-A)|+|B|-|(A\cap B)|$$
Rearranging I get
$$= |A|+|B| +|(B-A)|-|(A\cap B)|$$
So if I can show $|(B-A)|=|(A\cap B)|$ then I have what I need but I don't think it is possible. The closest I can get is $|(B-A)|=|(A\cap B)| = |(A - CB)|$.

Is there something I am not seeing?

Comment: Also we know that:

$$|A \cup B| = |A| + |B| - |A \cap B|$$

Answer (score 6):

Let $E$ be a large set containing both $A,B$ and for each $C \subset E$ we define $\chi_C: E \to \{0 ,1 \} $ to be the characteristic function of the set, that is

$$\chi_C(x)=1 \mbox{ if } x \in C \mbox{ and 0 otherwise}$$

Then, the following are well known/easy to prove

$$ |C|= \sum_{x \in E} \chi(x)$$
$$\chi_{A \cup B}= \chi_A+\chi_B-\chi_A\chi_B$$
$$\chi_{A \cap B}= \chi_A\chi_B \,.$$

Then

$$|A\cup B|+|A\cap B|= \sum_{x \in E} \left( \chi_A(x)+\chi_B(x)-\chi_A(x)\chi_B(x)\right)  +\sum_{x \in E} \left( \chi_A(x)\chi_B(x)\right)$$
$$ =\sum_{x \in E} \left( \chi_A(x)\right) +\sum_{x \in E} \left( \chi_B(x)\right) =|A|+|B|$$

**P.S.** Characteristic functions are in my opinion the simplest way to prove relations with sets. The other useful relations are:

$$A=B \Leftrightarrow \chi_A=\chi_B$$
$$A \subset B \Leftrightarrow \chi_A \leq\chi_B$$
$$\chi_{A \backslash B}= \chi_A - \chi_A \chi_B$$
$$\chi_{A \Delta B}= \chi_A+\chi_B - 2\chi_A \chi_B=\left(\chi_A-\chi_B \right)^2$$

Answer (score 4):

Although I'm pretty late to the party here's how I would have solve this problem. N.S. already gave a neat answer, but a second approach harms no one so here I go:

First decompose $A$, $B$ and $A\cap B$ into disjoint sets:

$(1)\;A = (A\setminus B)\cup(A\cap B)$

$(2)\;B = (B\setminus A)\cup (A\cap B)$

$(3)\;A\cup B = (A\setminus B)\cup (B\setminus A)\cup(A\cap B)$

This gives us

$(1^{\prime})\;|A| = |A\setminus B|+|A\cap B|$

$(2^{\prime})\;|B| = |B\setminus A|+|A\cap B|$

$(3^{\prime})\;|A\cup B| = |A\setminus B|+|B\setminus A|+|A\cap B|$

All that is left now is to bring together the equations above:

$$
\begin{align}
|A\cup B| &=|A\setminus B|+|B\setminus A|+|A\cap B|\\
&=|A|-|A\cap B|+|B|-|A\cap B|+|A\cap B|\\
&=|A|+|B|-|A\cap B|
\end{align}
$$

which implies $|A|+|B|=|A\cup B|+|A\cap B|$.

Answer (score 2):

Your initial "$|A\cup B|+|A\cap B| = |A\cup(B-A)|+|B-(A\cap B)|$" is wrong, because $|A\cup B|=|A\cup(B-A)|$ but $|A\cap B|\ne|B-(A\cap B)|.$

Your arguments can be corrected and completed like this:

- $|A\cup B|=|A\cup(B\setminus A)|=|A|+|B\setminus A|$ (the second equality is due to the fact that $A$ and $B\setminus A$ are disjoint).
- $|B\setminus A|+|A\cap B|=|(B\setminus A)\cup(A\cap B)|=|B|$ (the first equality is due to the fact that $B\setminus A$ and $A\cap B$ are disjoint).

From these two facts, the claim follows.